# VBA Query Table

Tags: vba, csv

I'm trying to bring in a CSV file (In the Legacy way, without formatting to the cells etc)

However I am getting run-time error '1004' on line Set = oQT, I am unsure why it looks like everything is defined..?

```
Sub importcsv()

Dim sSQL As String
Dim oQt As QueryTable
Dim ws As Worksheet
    
Set ws = Worksheets("Update")

strFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.csv),*.csv", , "CATIA Data")

Set oQt = ws.QueryTables.Add(strFile, ws.Range("A1"), sSQL)

oQt.Refresh

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the value of `sSQL`? It looks like it's just an empty string.

Comment: You do not get error 1004 from Excel when something is not defined. You get it when you are not passing correct arguments.

Comment: At https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.querytables.add has this for the `Sql` parameter - "...You cannot use this argument when a QueryTable object, text file, or ADO or DAO Recordset object is specified as the data source."

Answer (score 0):

**Your error:**

@TimWilliams already answered with `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.querytables.add`

> has this for the Sql parameter - "...You cannot use this argument when
> a QueryTable object, text file, or ADO or DAO Recordset object is
> specified as the data source."

---

**Possible solution:**

Use Data > From text/csv and select your csv. It will set-up your querytable for you.

OleDb driver and `.CommandType = xlCmdSql`

Now, this might violate your condition:

> In the Legacy way, without formatting to the cells etc

You can have simple format with:

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("data").TableStyle = vbNullString
```

---

**VBA:**

Example code would be like:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub SetUpImportFromCsv()

    ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="data", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents(""path\data.csv""),[Delimiter="","", Columns=12, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.Csv])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Promoted Headers"" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Source, [PromoteAllScalars=true])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#""Promoted Headers"",{{"""", Int64.Type}, {""PointOfCare"", typ" & _
        "e text}, {""ServiceType"", type text}, {""Title"", type text}, {""Url"", type text}, {""BusinessName"", type text}, {""ServiceDescription"", type text}, {""Address"", type text}, {""Tel"", type text}, {""Website"", type text}, {""AreaServed"", type text}, {""Ages"", type text}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"""
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=data;Extended Properties=""""" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [data]")
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .ListObject.DisplayName = "data"
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```